# jquerymobile datebox for label clicks

Tags: datetime, jquery-mobile, datebox

The current jquerymobile implementation of datebox (or some plugin like jtsage) pops up a datebox for text input. Is there anyway to extend it to cases where I want to show the datebox when the user click a label (or any random text)?

For example, in my case http://jsfiddle.net/sonyisme/UEmh3/1/, I want to show the datebox when users click on the text "8/1/2012-8/7/2012".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, [datebox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/opt/open.html) has a `open` method

So you can do something like

```
$('#myLabel').on('click', function() {
  $('#mydate').datebox('open');
});
```

Edit:

OK so you don't want a input displayed at all, as I mentioned in my comment I did something like that once with the `Datebox` plugin, what I needed to do was wrap it in a div that I just hid from the viewport by setting it's z-index to -1. The thing is the `z-index` had to be changed in code (basically after the plugin was initialized).  Here's some example code

HTML

```
 <div  class="hdnDateBoxCnt width25Percent"> 
                  <input type="date" name="myDateBox" id="myDateBox" data-role="datebox"
                     data-options='{"mode":"calbox",  "disableManualInput": true, "noButtonFocusMode": true}' />
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.hdnDateBoxCnt 
{
  position:absolute;
  /* z index needs to be set in code */   
}
```

JS

```
$('.hdnDateBoxCnt').css('z-index', '-1');
```

Just a note I used the code/markup with a earlier version of `datebox` so the `data-options` may have changed a bit. I have since switched to using the [MobiScroll](http://mobiscroll.com/) plugin.

Comment: Thanks. That still requires an input field, right? In my example here http://jsfiddle.net/sonyisme/UEmh3/1/ I don't want any input field. I want to be able to click the text and show the datebox.

Comment: It requires an input field but that input field can be hidden and you can just pull the value from the input.

Comment: I've tried but unfortunately the <input name="focusmode2" type="hidden" /> does not work with datebox. It will still show a large input field.

Comment: It's definitely doable, I've done something along those lines in the past, I think I may have had to wrap the input in a div and hide the div (I'm not sure but I may have had to hide it by keeping it off the viewport instead of just `display:none`. I ended up switching to the [mobiscroll](http://mobiscroll.com/) plugin in instead (I found it to be faster, at least it was at the time). I'll try and find the code and markup I used and post that.